# Couchbase group by name and collect field values

Tags: couchbase, sql++, nosql-aggregation

coming from mongoDB for 5 years, now just studying/trying Couchbase. I have a test data, which I want to group by city, and collect/push all `main.temp` values to a field. this can be done in mongoDB aggregation by `$push` or `$addToSet`

test data

```
{
    "city": "a",
    "main": {
        temp: 1
    }
},
{
    "city": "a",
    "main": {
        temp: 2
    }
},
{
    "city": "b",
    "main": {
        temp: 3
    }
},
{
    "city": "b",
    "main": {
        temp: 4
    }
}
```

I want the result to be like this, if possible, I want to sort the temp array to desc/asc

```
{
    "city": "a",
    "temp": [1, 2],
},
{
    "city": "b",
    "temp": [4, 3],
},
```

I tried something using the gui query from admin, but it doesn't give me the exact result I want.

```
select name, max(main.temp) as temp
from weather103
group by city
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I think I got the answer, by using `array_agg`

```
select city, array_agg(main.current_temp) as temp
from weather103
group by city
order by temp desc
```

Comment: Seems correct, 
For clarity please attach your results output.

Answer (score 0):

@Hokutosei, Welcome to Couchbase!

Checkout these resources and tutorials to get you started with queries quickly.
http://query.pub.couchbase.com/tutorial/#1
http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/getting-started/first-n1ql-query.html

We also have pretty active forum to ask questions. 
https://forums.couchbase.com/

Comment: thank you, done with the tutorial. I will look into the forums.